# The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, oledb, oledbconnection

I have a small method that basically checks if a check box is checked or un-check when the Page loads.

I do however get the above error message, stating that it cannot find the table 'tblProducts' which I find strange as the table does exist in the database.
Why do I get this OleDbException?

this is what I have done.

```
public void checkedOrNot(CheckBox chk, string column, string table)
{
    string codevalue;
    Session["exeFilePath"] = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath;
    using (OleDbConnection myOLEDBConn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"]))
    {
        bool value = false;

        codevalue = Request.QueryString["code"];
        myOLEDBConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = myOLEDBConn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ['" + column + "'] FROM ['" + table + "'] WHERE [CODE] = '" + codevalue + "'";
        OleDbDataReader dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dbReader.Read())
        {
            value = (bool)dbReader["" + column + ""];
        }
        if (value == true)
        {
            chk.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            chk.Checked = false;
        }
    }

}


checkedOrNot(chkPreview, "PreviewLibraryChecked", "tblProducts");
```

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ['" + column + "'] FROM ['" + table + "'] WHERE [CODE] = '" + codevalue + "'";
```

with this one

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [" + column + "] FROM [" + table + "] WHERE [CODE] = '" + codevalue + "'";
```